# Color sides of a surface in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

Is there an easy way to color sides of a surface in different colors using Asymptote?

Comment: What have you tried? That is, do you have a surface that others can use for their answer?

Comment: Two surfaces with a tiny offset?

Comment: @g.kov I thought to do this, but is there a better way?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: I would be surprised, 
if the Asymptote has this feature. 
Besides, this would be confusing 
for one-sided surfaces.

Comment: I agree that it is unlikely Asymptote has this feature, and that two surfaces with a tiny offset is likely the best you can do.